# Jrun in apache config during migration

Tags: apache-2.2, coldfusion, migration

I am migrating a bunch of websites to new servers and one of them has config options I have not encountered before, specifically:

```
<IfModule mod_jrun.c>
   JRunConfig Serverstore /usr/local/jrun4/lib/wsconfig/1/somewebsite.com-store
   JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:9009
</IfModule>
```

From some google searches it apears to be a coldfusion configuration option, HOWEVER there are no cfm files in the website, what do I need to install to move forward with the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have CFM files, you don't need JRun configs. [JRun has been "End-of-Life'd"](http://www.adobe.com/products/jrun/productinfo/faq/eod/)

Comment: Thanks!, that is what I ended up doing, but I wasn't sure if it was causing an error I didn't find when testing post migration. I was worried that this was going to haunt me down the line, so thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Look to see if mod_jrun.c is being loaded elsewhere in the config file, if not, you can safely remove those lines. Alternatively, comment out those lines and restart Apache to see if anything has trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'd up vote you but I dont have enough reputation points yet